# multiple IF statements in a function - OOP

Tags: php, function, object, if-statement

im wanting to check whether a inputted triangle is either a isosceles, equal etc.. the first if statement works, but once i introduce the second one it says unexpected t_else, here is the code...

```
public function typeOfTriangle()
{ 
        if ($this->sideOneLength == $this->sideTwoLength && $this->sideTwoLength == $this->baseLength) {
            echo "<h1>Equilateral Triangle</h1>";
        else if ($this->sideOneLength == $this->sideTwoLength OR $this->sideOneLength == $this->baseLength OR $this->sideTwoLength == $this->baseLength) {
            echo "<h1>Isosceles Triangle</h1>";
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You forgot the first closing brace `}` after your `echo` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is even better? ( Based on the example from Vlad Preda:

```
public function getSides()
{
    return array($this->sideOneLength, $this->sideTwoLength, $this->sideThreeLength);
}

public function typeOfTriangle()
{
    $uniqueSides = count(array_unique($this->getSides()));

    switch ($uniqueSides) {
      case 1:
        return "Equilateral";
        break;

      case 2:
        return "Isosceles";
        break;

      default:
        return "Normal triangle";
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
public function typeOfTriangle()
{ 
        if ($this->sideOneLength == $this->sideTwoLength && $this->sideTwoLength == $this->baseLength) {
            echo "<h1>Equilateral Triangle</h1>";
        }else if ($this->sideOneLength == $this->sideTwoLength OR $this->sideOneLength == $this->baseLength OR $this->sideTwoLength == $this->baseLength) {
            echo "<h1>Isosceles Triangle</h1>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a brace `}`

```
        if ($this->sideOneLength == $this->sideTwoLength && $this->sideTwoLength == $this->baseLength) {
            echo "<h1>Equilateral Triangle</h1>";
        }
        else if ($this->sideOneLength == $this->sideTwoLength OR $this->sideOneLength == $this->baseLength OR $this->sideTwoLength == $this->baseLength) {
            echo "<h1>Isosceles Triangle</h1>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different, more readable approach:

```
public function getSides()
{
    return array($this->sideOneLength, $this->sideTwoLength, $this->sideThreeLength);
}

public function typeOfTriangle()
{
    $uniqueSides = count(array_unique($this->getSides()));

    if ($uniqueSides == 1) {
        return "Equilateral";
    } elseif ($uniqueSides == 2) {
        return "Isosceles";
    } else {
        return "Normal triangle";
    }
}
```